# in-app purchase model based on collectionview / tableview selection

Tags: ios, uitableview, in-app-purchase, uicollectionview, storekit

I'm trying to implement in-app purchases in collection view of 30 items. Items represent images that are buyable. The collection view has **allowsMultipleSelection** set to true. The user should have the option to buy 1,2,3,12... pretty much whatever number of images in collection view. The price of purchase updates based on the number of items selected in collection view. How would someone implement such business model?

So far, the only option I could come up with is to implement 30 non-consumable iAP for 1 item, 15iAP for the case if user selects 2 items, 10iAP for the case if user selects 10 items in collection view and so forth... The number of all iAP in iTunesConnect using this approach is over 100. Way to much error prone work. Is there a better way?

The same business model could be used with tableView with **allowsMultipleSelection** set to true.